# GLSL shader wont compile, can someone help me find out why?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've been staring at this for too long and I'm too new to GLSL to know what is wrong. All I know is that when checking to see if the vertex shader compiles, it says that it could not do so. If someone could help me find out what I've done wrong that would be amazing.

textureShader.vert

```
#version 140

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 textCoord;

varying vec2 TextCoord;
varying vec3 lightDir,normal;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    lightDir = normalize(vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position));
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    gl_Position = position;
}
```

textureShader.frag

```
#version 140

uniform sampler2D texUnit;

varying vec2 TextCoord;
varying vec3 lightDir,normal;

void main()
{
    vec3 ct,cf;
    vec4 texel;
    float intensity,at,af;
    intensity = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);

    cf = intensity * (gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse).rgb + gl_FrontMaterial.ambient.rgb;
    af = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a;
    texel = texture2D(texUnit, TextCoord);

    ct = texel.rgb;
    at = texel.a;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ct * cf, at * af);

}
```

What I'm doing to check the compilation. DBOUT is a function to write to the Visual Studio output box.

```
glCompileShader(shader_vp);
validateShader(shader_vp, vsFile);

GLint compiled;
glGetShaderiv(shader_vp, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
if (!compiled){
    DBOUT("Couldn't Compile Vertex Shader: Aborting Mission\n");
    abort();
}


glCompileShader(shader_fp);
validateShader(shader_fp, fsFile);

glGetShaderiv(shader_fp, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);

if (!compiled){
    DBOUT("Couldn't Compile Fragment Shader: Aborting Mission\n");
    abort();
}
```

The output I receive:

```
Couldn't Compile Vertex Shader: Aborting Mission
Debug Error!
```

**SOLVED**

So with everyones help I go this to compile. I had to replace these lines:

```
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    gl_Position = position;
```

With these ones:

```
    TextCoord = vec2(textCoord);

    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position,1.0f);
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: grab the log with glGetShaderInfoLog​ and print that

Comment: Check logs, post MCVE, etc.  Make sure your `#version` directive line has a newline at the end.

Comment: @ratchetfreak printing the info log gives me the following
    E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't look at your shader but you can get an error message from the compiler with something like:

```
auto error = GLint();

::glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &error);

if(error != GL_TRUE)
{       
    auto length = GLint();

    ::glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

    if(length > 0)
    {
        auto log = std::vector<GLchar>(length, 0);

        ::glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, nullptr, &log[0]);

        auto message = std::string(log.begin(), log.end());
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Gotta say... I don't see much use in declaring something `auto` if you have the compiler deduce its type by writing `= GLint()`. Seems like you could save a lot of typing if you _didn't_ use `auto`.

Comment: I use auto everywhere and that kind of declaration ensures it's always initialised.  The compiler can't deduce the type given the variable's future use (unfortunately).  It's just a general rule I use.

Answer (score 1):

One possible error in the shader might be:

> gl_Position = position;

The gl_Position should be of type vec4, but the position is an attribute of vec3, you probably forgot to do something like:

> gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);

Comment: Changing that gave me a different error, so I'm not totally sure if it's just one thing going wrong. After making this change I get a new error (checked with glGetError()) on this call: 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(tCoordLoc[i]);

Comment: Ok so the shader error has gone away, right? The glEnableVertexAttribArray is not part of the shown code so I am not sure, but I guess that you pass the wrong argument. This function is used to enable the vertexAttribs that you specify using glVertexAttribPointer and not the location of a uniform.